# spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES error when running react native project on emulator

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use 
    react-native run-android
to install my react-native application on an android studio emulator. 
I have checked with abd-devices that the emulator is available, and I have ran npm-install.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest version of android studio, and the latest Pixel 2 XL API 28.

I get the following error:

spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES

```
Error: spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:998:20)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:622:24)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:650:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/user/react/front-end/project/node_modules    /react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/home/user/react/front-end/project/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/home/user/react/front-end/project/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

I have tried restarting my PC and the emulator several times.
Any ideas?

UPDATE: I reinstalled JDK, npm, react-native-cli and android studio. It still gives me the exact same error. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the count of your inotify watchers? https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Comment: @Andrew Tried it now. It did nothing :(

Comment: problem is not specific to emulator usage, affects any unix-derived system (tested on Linux, macOS, Windows) works fine on Windows because file modes/ACLs are not relevant on Windows platform. this could be addressed within the rn git repo itself, in that regard accepted answer is a workaround.

Answer (score 687, accepted):

I fixed this problem with:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

the chmod command sets the permissions of files or directories.
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm

Comment: fixed the problem successfully. But it  would be nice if you explain what it does. Would've been useful to many people i think.

Comment: @Grez.Kev this command makes gradlew files into executable. Which help code to give a run. 
This solution saves my hours. Thnx

Comment: My right relative path is platforms/android/gradlew and it works

Comment: I do not have gradlew directory under my android dir, what sould I do?

Comment: chmod 755 - 755 means read and execute access for everyone and also write access for the owner of the file.

Comment: @BlueBot `gradlew` is not a directory. It's a file (gradle wrapper) that is part of your project.

Comment: This definitely worked. But just wondering why this wasn't taken as a precaution for React Native development or mentioned in the docs...

Comment: In monorepo projects you should be run it in mobile folder or change command to `chmod 755 packages/mobile/android/gradlew `

Comment: @jinkey This command didn't work for me, I use mac Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Worked for me on an early 2015 MacBook Air running macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 78):

`gradlew` file permissions should be updated, you can resolve it by changing the permission, run the following command

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

it will give (read,write,execute) permission for the user(owner), also (read, execute) for group and other users.

Answer (score 18):

It turns out that It's not `gradle` but it's `android/gradlew`.
run the below command inside the root directory:

```
$ chmod +x android/gradlew
```

Now run

```
$ yarn android            
# OR   
$ npm run android 
# OR
$ npx react-native run-android
```

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 17):

I tried the above solution.but in my case I had to use sudo because of the permission issue. You can resolve it by running the command

`sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew`

Comment: Can you explain why you don't use the same path as in the other answers?

Answer (score 3):

On the first approved answer from @Jinkey, in case you are wondering where to run this command, like in my case on Mac, follow these steps:

1. In your terminal navigate to your project folder `cd <project folder>`, make sure the path to your project is correct.
2. Then once in the folder, run the command by copying and pasting as is `chmod 755 android/gradlew`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew` works perfectly fine for this issue in mac!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the react native cli project directory then run this command below :

```
sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

then run the command:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

then start the metro (if it is not started automatically) by following command:

```
npx react-native start
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was go to folder one above your project and run chmod -R a+rwx nameOfTheProject/ or if that doesn't work chmod -R 777 nameOfTheProject/

Solution found on this link
https://edwardbeazer.com/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/

Answer (score 0):

On MacBook Air M1 chip `chmod 755 android/gradlew` works great. Also add the below line in the `android/local.properties` file.

```
sdk.dir = /Users/YourUserNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score -1):

#### FIXED

Just run this:

```bash
sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005690/2227743).