# Windows error :spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES error when running react native project on emulator

Tags: android, windows, react-native, android-emulator, expo

Am trying to run react native using  `react-native run-android` but I get the above error. I was having issues getting my detached expo to run on android emulator and I keep getting this error  `Error running app. Have you installed the app already using Android Studio? Since you are detached you must build manually. Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=....` 
After hours of futile effort i tried running  `react-native run-android` but I keep getting the above error (title). solution online [spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES error when running react native project on emulator udara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541734/spawnsync-gradlew-eacces-error-when-running-react-native-project-on-emulator-u) shows its a permission issue and that it can be resolved with 
`chmod 755 android/gradlew` 
since am using a windows system i tried 
`ICACLS "android/gradlew" /grant:r "Administrator:(F)" /C`
but I still get the same error. am not really good with icacls so I may be wrong. any assistance is highly appreciated.
My emulator is working perfectly cause i did a  `adb devices` check and its their. I even have the emulator already open on my window

Answer (score 28):

open terminal in your root project react-native and type : 
`cd android && chmod -R 777 ./gradlew && cd ..`

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Comment: The question was about Windows. Also, `chmod 777` is never the right solution.